# Install Ubuntu in triple boot alongside OS X El Capitan and Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

This is my current situation:

[image: disks and partitions]

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on /dev/disk1s5 and have it working alongside the existing El Capitan and Windows 7 (BOOTCAMP) partition on the same disk.
I recently tried to install another distro on the same partition but I got the Hybrid MBR all messed up and had to manually rebuild it using Fdisk; everything boots normally now, but I'd like to avoid needing to re-do those operations.

So, how do I proceed? Do I necessarily need rEFInd?
Seeing as I added my chosen partition to the MBR, should I be able to just install Ubuntu without rEFInd, if I were to install it in legacy mode?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not know Mac. But Ubuntu will boot in UEFI mode or BIOS mode from a gpt partitioned drive on a PC. You do not need the hybrid partitions for Ubuntu, only for Windows in BIOS mode. http://askubuntu.com/questions/650194/repair-windows-boot-loader-after-installing-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro

Comment: You can try a VM within OSX or Windows.. clean and easy to maintain. Why go throught the trouble of a triple boot?.. Just adding a perspective, Not a definiteve answer.

Comment: @AravindR I've never really liked running an OS on a VM; I prefer setting up a separate partition...