# Weird partitioning issue on MacBook Air

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, macbook

I have a working triple-boot system on a MacBook Air (Mac OS X + Windows 7 + Ubuntu) that I achieved some time ago by following various tutorials.

Now I'd like to spice it up a bit by reinstalling Ubuntu with full disk encryption (using [this great tutorial](http://blog.botux.fr/en/2015/09/ubuntu-installation-manual-full-disk-encryption-lvm-on-luks/)) and removing Mac OS X entirely, since I never use it anymore.

But I'm hitting a roadblock: as soon as I touch the GPT, no matter how little I change, **Windows becomes unbootable!**

Here is the current, working partition table (Linux gdisk command p)

```
Disk /dev/sda: 490234752 sectors, 233.8 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): DC542B27-E782-479A-B17F-AAB05FACFA6C
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 490234718
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2877 sectors (1.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          411648       160409599   76.3 GiB    8300  
   3       160409600       168409087   3.8 GiB     8200  
   4       168409088       244826335   36.4 GiB    AF00  Apple_HFS_Untitled_2
   5       244826336       246095871   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD
   6       246095872       490233855   116.4 GiB   0700  BOOTCAMP
```

Partitions 2 and 3 are Linux root and swap respectively.

This is the protective MBR (command: r o)

```
Disk size is 490234752 sectors (233.8 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x4B9CA30C
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1    246095871   primary     0xEE
   2      *      246095872    490233855   primary     0x07
```

What I'd like to do is to remove GPT partitions 2 to 4 (not to be confused with MBR partition 2 above), replacing them with a 256MB Linux boot and a LUKS partition holding everything else. (I'll keep the Mac OS X recovery just in case I need some utility to write to nvram or something.)

I can easily do it with commands: d 2, d 3, d 4, n 2 default +256M, n 3 default default. The result is thus:

```
...
Total free space is 869 sectors (434.5 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640          933927   256.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   3          933928       244826335   116.3 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   5       244826336       246095871   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD
   6       246095872       490233855   116.4 GiB   0700  BOOTCAMP
```

Printing the protective MBR shows the exact same table as before.

And yet, if I write this to disk and reboot, Windows won't boot anymore! even though I haven't changed its partition, nor the protective MBR.

If I hold Alt during boot and choose Windows, I get a **weird sequence of screens that end in a Grub command prompt!** Where is that Grub coming from, is a mystery.

Luckily I had a foreboding that something like this might happen, so I made a complete Clonezilla backup before touching anything. Now I can easily restore the system to the working triple boot state and try again. But no matter what I try, I break it!

How can I modify these partitions without borking Windows?

Edit—here are the weird Grub screens when I try to boot Windows after changing the GPT:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the second screen it mentions 3 partitions of type 0xEE. Where are they coming from? Where is this Grub coming from in the first place??

Comment: I do not understand. If you want Windows you have to keep the partition 2 as that is the NTFS type 07 partition. And you have the hybrid partitioning scheme which can be difficult to keep in sync. I might reinstall Windows in UEFI boot mode as then it can use gpt and you can forget about the hybrid partitioning. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html and http://askubuntu.com/questions/650194/repair-windows-boot-loader-after-installing-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro

Comment: @oldfred Yes, I'm keeping GPT partition 6 = MBR partition 2 intact, as that is the NTFS. I'd rather not reinstall Windows as I have a lot of stuff on there.

Comment: I do not know Mac, but those that do may understand your configuration if you run this: May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/