# Corrupt GPT tables?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.  When launching gparted from the terminal:

```
sudo gparted
```

I'm getting a warning:

```
Both the primary and backup GPT tables are corrupt.  Try making a fresh 
table, and using Parted's rescue feature to recover partitions.
```

My question:  is this anything to worry about?

I have run this command:

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
```

and it gives me back

```
Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.
```

and

```
No problems found. 158101641 free sectors (75.4 GiB) available in 3
segments, the largest of which is 157839360 (75.3 GiB) in size.
```

Is this simply a false positive from gparted?  I noticed this started happening after I moved a Mac Recovery partition on my drive.  I have 6 partitions:  EFI System Partition, Macintosh HD, Recovery HD, linux-swap, and ext4 for Ubuntu.  Thanks!

Comment: You cannot move a gpt partition. Gpt has GUID's inside the partition and the primary & backup gpt partition table that must match. This probably the error. You may be able to fix with gdisk. And best not to have hybrid MBR. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html
convert hybrid to protective MBR gdisk experts commands  p, x, n, p, w
http://askubuntu.com/questions/650194/repair-windows-boot-loader-after-installing-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro
 & http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html